# Notarized documents with hyperledger indy

Tags: hyperledger, blockchain, hyperledger-indy

I am trying to build a notarized documents system and exploring hyperledger indy as a tool to manage identities of people that sign the documents. I would like to validate signature of each document so each document would have a separate wallet and would keep all the signatures in it. But I would also like to browse the documents.
Is such a system possible with hyperledger indy?

Answer (score 0):

Hyperledger Indy supports Verifiable Credentials and Claims. It has a credential schema feature. Hence using this schema you can create a repository of documents. DID of users can be associated with the verifiable credentials from the Document. We can also implement metadata on the documents in Hyperledger Indy. Querying Metadata and Credentials is a possibility. Keeping a separate wallet for every document may not be a scalable design in Hyperledger Indy based Architecture.However it is quite possible to design Indy Wallets for Documents with Digital Signature Aggregation features. Hyperledger Indy supports BLS signatures in the out of the box implementation. We will  need to use Indy Crypto libraries for this purpose.